# How can I insert bootstrap-autohindingnavbar into ember application?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm new to ember, and I've been searching a lot for doing that `navbar-fixed-top` hides when scrolling in an ember app. The code is:

```
$(".navbar-fixed-top").autoHidingNavbar()
```

That's all. It seems easy. But when it comes to where to put it and how to deal with this simple expression, I found no clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put that code into the [`didInsertElement()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement) event on a `view`.

Assuming you're using [`ember-cli`](http://ember-cli.com), create a view (note, application is the default template for your app, you should replace application with whatever your template is named):

```
ember g view application
```

Then locate the view at `app/views/application.js` and you can implement it like so:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.$(".navbar-fixed-top").autoHidingNavbar();
  }
});
```